# save() not updating the table in database

Tags: django, database

I have to update 2 tables in database every time user visit a page.

**this is working:**

```
order_order = OrderTable.no_objects.get(order_number=order_id)

order_order.status = 'updated status'
order_order.save()
```

**This is not working:** (related with first table through foreign key)

```
order_item = ItemsTable.objects.filter(order_id__order_number=order_id)
for i in range(order_item.count()):
        order_item[i].qty = i + 5
        order_item[i].qty_nextMonth = i + 30
        order_item[i].save()
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong in 2nd part of code. It's not updating the database.

Comment: By using `[i]` you each time make a separate fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you write `order_item[i]`, you make a separate fetch, and you return an `ItemsTable` item from the database. That means that if you set the `.qty = ...` attribute of that object, it is simply ignored, since the next `order_item[i]` will trigger a new fetch. Your `order_item[i].save()` updates the record in the database, but with the values that have been retrieved just from a fetch from the database.

It is better to simply iterate over the queryset, and thus maintain a reference to the *same* `ItemsTable` object:

```
order_items = ItemsTable.objects.filter(order_id__order_number=order_id)
for i, order_item in enumerate(order_items):
        order_item.qty = i + 5
        order_item.qty_nextMonth = i + 30
        order_item.save()
```

This is more efficient as well, since enumerating over a queryset forces evaluation, and hence you fetch all objects at once.

As of [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can use [**`.bulk_update(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update), to update in bulk an iterable of objects.

Comment: This is giving error. 'ItemsTable' object is not iterable.

Comment: It should be `order_items`. Did you by any change use `.get()` over `.filter()`?

Comment: No, I am using filter. I don't know why it's saying filter() object is not iterable.

Comment: @sandeep: it does not say that, somewhere you iterate over an `ItemsTable` *object*, so something like `for ... in some_itemtableobject:` I am quite sure that this is not in the code fragment that is posted here.

Comment: one more thing, my code in question worked once. I don't why it stopped working or how it worked once.

Comment: @sandeep: it is definitely possible that it works if you keep a reference to the object, like `my_obj = order_items[i]; my_obj.qty = 42; my_obj.save()`